# Is there a function in Pygame to save a portion of the screen as an image?

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on making a drawing program in Pygame. All features are basically complete except for the ability to save your image. Is there any built in Pygame function that does this, or will I have to find some other way (E.G. taking a screenshot or something).

Comment: crop the screen, then use `pygame.image.save()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`screen` is a [Surface](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object which has method [subsurface(Rect)](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface) to get part of surface - and this part will be also a `Surface` object.

And there is function [pygame.image.save(surface, filename)](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.save)

---

Other method: at start create smaller `Surface` and draw on this surface (instead of drawing directly on `screen`) and `blit()` this surface on `screen` to display it and `save()`  this surface to file.

You can even use many surfaces and keep them on list to create function `Undo`. When you use new tool then you duplicate surface and put it on list. When you use `Undo` then you get last surface from list.

Comment: Thank you! This should be perfect! Also, funnily enough, I just finished implementing a similar `undo()` function, so great minds think alike I guess.

Comment: Also, I would've helpful voted this, but I guess I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: separated surface could be used also to draw image bigger then screen. You can create bigger image and display only some subsurface and use some buttons to scroll surface.

Comment: as I know when you mark answer as accepted then you may have enough reputation but you have to wait few minutes to upvote it.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know you could do that!

Answer (score 1):

If it's a drawing game, then you'll probably find it very easy to manually make the image.

I know it sounds scary, but it really isn't, especially in python.

You can use [PyPng](https://github.com/drj11/pypng/) to convert a 2D array into an image, as I assume you already use a 2D array to store the drawing

Comment: I actually store the lines required to make the finished product (using the draw.line function). Is there any easy way to do that, if you know?